# SQL move row from one table to another with unmatched columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have found plenty of examples on how to insert into using a select then delete however,

I am looking to move data from one table to another and the columns ARE NOT matched
for example

table1 (`id`, `location`, `lat`, `lon`, `date_added`)

table2 (`id`, `location`, `lat`, `lon`, `date_added`, `requested`)

essentially I would like to insert into table2 a row from table1 and add the $_SESSION['user_name'] to the requested field, and then delete the original row from the first table.

I have tried a few different things

```
$sql = "START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO bia_signs_pending (SELECT * FROM bia_signs WHERE id = ".$_GET['sign_id'].');

DELETE FROM bia_signs WHERE id = '          .$_GET['sign_id'].';
UPDATE bia_signs_pending SET requested='    .$_SESSION['user']['email'].
'WHERE id = '.$_GET['sign_id'].';
COMMIT;';
```

//this one breaks because the columns do not match

any suggestions?

Comment: you should read up on prepared queries and sql injection attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT` with column names

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (id, location, lat, lon, date_added)
SELECT id, location, lat, lon, date_added 
FROM table1 
WHERE ...
```

and you can add constants into an `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (id, location, lat, lon, date_added, requested)
SELECT id, location, lat, lon, date_added, 'Jonny'
FROM table1
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your insert

```
INSERT INTO bia_signs_pending (SELECT FROM bia_signs WHERE id = ".$_GET['sign_id'].');
```

to

```
INSERT INTO bia_signs_pending (id, location, lat, lon, date_added) VALUES (SELECT * FROM bia_signs WHERE id = '".$_GET['sign_id'].');
```

Comment: my table is quite simplified in the example here. but how would I then append the additional field "requested".  Would I need to add an UPDATE clause to the Transaction or is there a more efficient way to add it to the insert clause?

Comment: I tried it this way but I think the table name has to be in front of the (columnName, colname2...) like Ian Kenney's post

Answer (score 0):

Change your INSERT statement, add list of fields you are selecting:

```
INSERT INTO bia_signs_pending (id, location, lat, lon, date_added)
            SELECT * FROM bia_signs WHERE id = '{$_GET['sign_id']}';
```

Comment: sorry. I made some edits before copy/pasting here so my original had the *

Comment: make sure about `'`, you are missing one on _GET  at the end of insert